# Determining the complement of 3 sets with limited information

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics

I have been assigned a question that is (seemingly) impossible to solve with the information I have been given. It goes something like this:

A group of athletes were surveyed to see what sports they play. The following results were obtained:

- 60 play soccer or basketball
- 13 play soccer and basketball
- 6 play all three
- 40 play soccer
- 32 play basketball
- 46 play hockey
- 31 play ONLY hockey
- 45 play soccer or basketball but NOT hockey
- 22 play at least two sports
- 74 play soccer or hockey

Determine how many athletes

1. Play at least one sport?
2. Play only one sport?
3. Do not play any sports?
4. Were surveyed in total?

---

Questions 1 and 2 are pretty straightforward. If they play one of the games, they belong in the union of all three sets. This can be found using inclusion-exclusion:
$$
S \cup B \cup H = S + B + H - (S \cap B) - (S \cap H) - (B \cap H) + (S \cap B \cap H)
$$
Since 22 play at least two sports, $(S \cap B) + (S \cap H) + (B \cap H) - 2(S \cap B \cap H) = 22$, and since 6 play all three, $(S \cap B) + (S \cap H) + (B \cap H) = 34$

With this, I can answer question 1: $40 + 32 + 46 - 34 + 6 = 90$ total athletes

Question 2, I also solved using the fact 22 play at least 2 sports. I modelled question 2 as $(S \cup B \cup H) - ((S \cap B) + (S \cap H) + (B \cap H) - 2(S \cap B \cap H)) = 90 - 22 = 68$ total athletes

---

My trouble arises from questions 3 and 4. My confusion is due to the fact I need the number from 3 to calculate 4 and the number from 4 to calculate 3, both of which are unknown (how is it possible to calculate how many do not play any of the sports if I don't know how many were surveyed in total and vice versa). I feel like I'm missing something obvious but I've been stuck on this for a while with no progress.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: That data does seem to be completely missing; none of the subsets mentioned contain any people who don't play any sports.  It could be none or a million.

We can't even go by the fact that they are all athletes: there are many athletic activities that are not these sports, or are even considered sports!

Comment: @DanUznanski I guess its an error with the question then... As a side note, do you think my answers to the first two questions look alright?

Comment: Your solutions look good to me!